# Money transfer from UK to Indian bank account?

Tags: india, money-transfer, iban

One of my friend is sending 100000 pounds to India, I have a bank account with Canara Bank here in India. He is asking for RIB and IBAN and I am not aware of it. Kindly tell me how to find this or write in answer if you know.

Answer (score 1):

> One of my friend is sending 100000 pounds to India,

Although you haven't asked, this is a large amount of funds and depending on why it is, there could be taxes to you or lot of paperwork.

> He is asking for RIB and IBAN and I am not aware of it.

India does not have IBAN. IBAN is mostly in Europe, Australia and New Zealand. You would need to give Bank Account Number and SWIFT BIC. The details can be found [here](http://www.canarabank.com/English/scripts/SWIFT.aspx). Best talk to your Branch to understand.